# Getting error when trying to build in Drools Workbench

Tags: drools, workbench, kie, drools-guvnor

I have installed Drools 7.7.0.Final war file in JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA  and trying to build a sample application. During build it is always throwing below exception. I am not able to proceed further. Please help to resolve this error.

```
13:39:37,501 ERROR [org.kie.workbench.common.services.refactoring.backend.server.indexing.AbstractFileIndexer] (Thread-529) Unable to index 'default://master@myteam/Mortgages/src/test/resources/mortgages/mortgages/Pricing%20low%20end.scenario'.: org.guvnor.common.services.shared.exceptions.GenericPortableException: An error occurred while executing the Local Build Config stage.
    at org.guvnor.common.services.backend.exceptions.ExceptionUtilities.handleException(ExceptionUtilities.java:46)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.datamodel.backend.server.DataModelServiceImpl.getModuleDataModel(DataModelServiceImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor161.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.datamodel.backend.server.service.DataModelService$1079160182$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getModuleDataModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.workbench.screens.testscenario.backend.server.indexing.TestScenarioFileIndexer.getModuleDataModelOracle(TestScenarioFileIndexer.java:77)
    at org.drools.workbench.screens.testscenario.backend.server.indexing.TestScenarioFileIndexer.fillIndexBuilder(TestScenarioFileIndexer.java:52)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.refactoring.backend.server.indexing.AbstractFileIndexer.toKObject(AbstractFileIndexer.java:78)
    at org.drools.workbench.screens.testscenario.backend.server.indexing.TestScenarioFileIndexer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toKObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.BatchIndex$3.visitFile(BatchIndex.java:186)
    at org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.BatchIndex$3.visitFile(BatchIndex.java:152)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:71)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:96)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:96)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:96)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:96)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:96)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:96)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:48)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:1031)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:1052)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing the Local Build Config stage.
    at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.continuePipeline(PipelineExecutor.java:126)
    at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.execute(PipelineExecutor.java:76)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.BuildPipelineInvoker.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(BuildPipelineInvoker.java:88)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.BuildPipelineInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(BuildServiceHelper.java:152)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper.localBuild(BuildServiceHelper.java:82)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.localBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl.build(BuildServiceImpl.java:69)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildInfoService.getBuildInfo(BuildInfoService.java:59)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildInfoService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getBuildInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.datamodel.backend.server.cache.LRUModuleDataModelOracleCache.makeModuleOracle(LRUModuleDataModelOracleCache.java:81)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.datamodel.backend.server.cache.LRUModuleDataModelOracleCache.assertModuleDataModelOracle(LRUModuleDataModelOracleCache.java:72)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.datamodel.backend.server.cache.LRUModuleDataModelOracleCache$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.assertModuleDataModelOracle(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.datamodel.backend.server.DataModelServiceImpl.getModuleDataModel(DataModelServiceImpl.java:91)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildConfig.BuildType.${input.build-type}
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildConfig$BuildType.valueOf(LocalBuildConfig.java:41)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildConfigExecutor.decodeBuildType(LocalBuildConfigExecutor.java:90)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildConfigExecutor.apply(LocalBuildConfigExecutor.java:56)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildConfigExecutor.apply(LocalBuildConfigExecutor.java:38)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildConfigExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.lambda$continuePipeline$0(PipelineExecutor.java:109)
    at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor$$Lambda$288/221017006.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:38)
    at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:33)
    at org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.continuePipeline(PipelineExecutor.java:94)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with underlying git repository which is used by kie-workbench. Make sure user has required write permissions on filesystem.

Comment: Tried giving full permission on the folder but still no luck :(

Comment: I have a similar question. Did you get any answer on this.?